# Terminology for breaking partition diagram into "L"'s

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

When one thinks about partitions, it's quite normal to consider pieces of the partition diagram, such as rows, columns, arms, legs, hooks, etc.

One decomposition of particular interest to me is when one breaks the partition into the hooks through the boxes $(k,k)$; that is, one pulls off the largest row and largest column as a single "L" and then continues this process with the left over partition.

> Is there any term for these special hooks and this decomposition of the partition?